# Green's identity formula

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-theorem

[image]

Instead, if we assume that $v\in C^\infty_c(U), u\in C^2(U)$. Will the second equality still hold? Since $v$ have compact support in U, the boundary term will just vanish and $-\int_Uu\Delta v dx$ should be well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it still holds. Note that you can find an open subset $\hat{U}$ such that
$$supp(v) \subset \hat{U} \subset U.$$
Now v and all its derivatives vanish outside of $\hat{U}$ and $u \in C^2(\bar{\hat{U}}).$ Note that the integration over $U$ is now the same as the integration over $\hat{U}$, hence
$$\int_U Dv \cdot Du\, dx =\int_{\hat{U}} Dv \cdot Du\, dx = -\int_{\hat{U}} u \Delta v \, dx + \int_{\partial\hat{U}}\frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu} u \, dS \\= -\int_{\hat{U}} u \Delta v \, dx = -\int_U u \Delta v \, dx.$$